# shared_ptr vs unique_ptr with arrays

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

this does not work:

```
std::shared_ptr <char[]> ptr(new char[100]);
ptr[10] = '\0';
```

and this works:

```
std::unique_ptr <char[]> ptr(new char[100]);
ptr[10] = '\0';
```

I get compliler error C2676, meaning that "does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator". Any idea why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So some thoughts:

- `std::shared_ptr<char[]> ptr(new char[100]);` should be a syntax error all by itself.
- For whatever reason, `unique_ptr` was enabled to support the `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` syntax. Some of the rationale can be found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/browse_thread/thread/469fcc136b8f2d42/f774bf6f81dd2af7?lnk=gst&q=auto_ptr%3CT%5B%5D%3E#f774bf6f81dd2af7).
- The `std::shared_ptr<T>::operator[]` call also doesn't work, because `std::shared_ptr` does not implement it, only `std::unique_ptr` does.

Comment: thanks for the reply. std::shared_ptr<char[]> ptr(new char[100]); works with vs2013 compiler.